# How to concate strings in a bash script to use in SQL-Statement?

Tags: command-line, bash, mysql, scripts

I would like to do the following in a bash script:

1. read some filenames out of an file with filenames
2. set a variable input path
3. concat 1. and 2.
4. use 3. in sql-statement

Here my code:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 INPath="/home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/"

 while 
 read line
 do
 RD="$line"
 RDFile="$INPath$RD"

 echo -e $RDFile

 ###MYSQLs:
 mysql -u root -D RD --local-infile << EOF
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$RDFile'
     INTO TABLE bv_tmp_all FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
 EOF
 ##### EOSQL

 done < /home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/allto468
```

The echo shows the right path and filenamen but mysql always says:

```
not found (Errcode: 2 - File or Directory not found)
```

I've tried different ways to concate the two strings but none worked :(

The following code works with mysql (without the concate) but it is not what I need:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 while 
 read line
 do

 RDFile="/home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/468-R11"

 echo -e $RDFile

 ###MYSQLs:
 mysql -u root -D RD --local-infile << EOF
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$RDFile'
     INTO TABLE bv_tmp_all FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
 EOF
 ##### EOSQL

 done < /home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/allto468
```

What is wrong with the concate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `allto468` itself has \r\n line endings, then $line will look like `468-R11\r`, and that file is surely not found.

Solutions

1. run `dos2unix` on the allto468 file to fix the issue once,
2. change the `done` line to

   ```
   done < <(sed 's/\r$//' /home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/allto468)
   ```

Comment: GREAT! It works! Thank you Glenn. Tiny things....

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `RDFile` doesn't exist in your first script. 
What do you have in `/home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/allto468`?
Are they filenames that really exist in `/home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/`?

I would add a test in the middle to check if the constructed path really exists, for example like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPath="/home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/"

while read line; do
    RD="$line"
    RDFile="$INPath$RD"
    echo $RDFile

    if ! test -f "$RDFile"; then
        echo error: file does not exist: $RDFile
        continue
    fi

    ###MYSQLs:
    mysql -u root -D RD --local-infile << EOF
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$RDFile'
 INTO TABLE bv_tmp_all FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
EOF
    ##### EOSQL
done < /home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/allto468
```

Comment: Thank you. The test says the file does not exist!!! But if I use the result of the echo directly than it works.... :( The echo shows the right path. What is wrong with the concate?

Comment: Do you run the script with a different user? If the script runs as a different user, it's possible that the user doesn't have permission to the containing directory, causing the test to fail.

Comment: I am root and gave 777 to the directory

Comment: And when you are root, can you read the content of that file? For example with `sudo head /path/to/file` ?

Comment: Yes I have all rights.... :(

Comment: and it runs even on my localhost

Comment: Did you really run that command? Just because you're root, that doesn't necessarily mean you can access. For example the home directory could be encrypted. Run that command. If that works, then the only thing I can think of is that there must be some tiny detail we're missing

Comment: Yes I did the sudo head on my console and took even the string from the echo statement!!! It works! But not in the script. Damn...

Comment: even a simple ls /home/bono/RD/BV-OUT/468-R11 works....

Comment: I need to go... and give it up for today! Thank you, Janos! Maybe tommorrow there is a solution...

Comment: I'm out of ideas... Sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a quoting problem to me. To get variable substitution to work, use '"', not "'", that is, replace:

```
mysql -u root -D RD --local-infile << EOF  
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$RDFile'  
INTO TABLE bv_tmp_all FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';  
EOF
```

with:

```
mysql -u root -D RD --local-infile << EOF
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "$RDFile"
INTO TABLE bv_tmp_all FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
EOF
```

To check for funny characters in the filename, `echo "$RDFile" | od -bc`.

Comment: Quoting was not the problem....The dos-in-file was!